# Run tests at package compilation

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is there a way to run tests (for instance, run a dedicated test procedure) while compiling a package? I would like to prevent a package from compiling if the tests inside fail...

I saw the `begin/end` part of the body cannot be used to achieve that because:

- this is after compilation, and I'd prefer to get the error sooner
- this is called only once (1st call after compilation)

Comment: Begin / end part of the body are not called once after compilation. They are called once per session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it's a good way. But generally, if you really wish, you can use [DDL trigger](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/triggers.htm#i6061): check for `ALTER PACKAGE .. COMPILE` statement and execute tests.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that, even if as you say I'm not sure this is the good way to go...